# Invalid argument (400) - Cannot find key of appropriate type to decrypt AP REP - AES256 CTS mode with HMAC SHA1-96

Tags: java, kerberos, dropwizard, spnego, mit-kerberos

The issue is observed with "curl --service-name test --negotiate:u http://localhost:8080/api". The command is used to test an API running in the same host protected by Kerberos.
SPN = "test/localhost@EXAMPLE.COM".

1. I have tried providing all access to Keytab.
2. Keytab is generated with "/CRYPTO All" flag.
3. All suggestions provided on Stackover flow have been tried.

Comment: Wait - are you using MIT Kerberos or Active Directory?

Comment: Hi John.. I’m using my own KDC and MIT Kerberos

Comment: Sorry, can't help you then.